# PHP Warning Division by zero

Tags: php

I have this code in my footer of my website:

```
<style>
@media only screen and (min-width:801px) {
footer .widget { width: <?php echo (102-2*$cnt)/$cnt; ?>%; }
#<?php echo $total_widgets['smt_footer_sidebar'][$cnt-1]; ?> { margin-right:0; }
}
</style>
```

I get a PHP Warning Division by zero error in my errorlog.

It's in line:

`footer .widget { width: <?php echo (102-2*$cnt)/$cnt; ?>%; }`

Can someone help me, please.

Answer (score 4):

Replace

```
<?php echo (102-2*$cnt)/$cnt; ?>
```

with

```
<?= $cnt != 0 ? (102-2*$cnt)/$cnt : 0 ; ?>     <-- condition ? true : false
```

or `100` instead of `0` at `false` position, it's up to you